# Bootable USB without an OS shows as Windows in Startup Manager

Tags: macos, bootcamp, startup, external-disk

I was going to do a clean install of El Capitan and I created a Bootable USB drive. After making the drive I done the usual, I restarted while I held down the option key to white I was presented a screen with startup disk option screen and predictably I found my usual HDD that my OS is on, my backup drive, and my bootable USB which is called "Windows".

[image]

That's weird since I've never installed Boot Camp on this machine.

When I boot from the "Windows" drive there's just a blank screen and the letter "J" flashing on it and nothing else happens.

[image]

Just a "J" in the top left of the screen.

What is this?

Comment: After some trial and error I tried booting without the USB bootable of El Capitan in and the "Windows" boot option that takes me to the "J" is gone.

Comment: Ok So I reformatted the bootable drive in a none_Journaled format, Fat32 just to test then tested again. Now a blank drive, still showed as "windows" in the boot screen, when I booted from it it say something like "Unreognised boot section" or something to that effect.

I can take this to mean the "J" stood for "Journaled" and it was what happens when you try to boot "windows" from a Journaled drive?

Thoughts? Anyone want to test to confirm just so anyone that comes finds the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously something went wrong in making the bootable USB stick.
It should be 8GB.
Why not use a little tool that does it for you:
Diskmaker_X,  see http://diskmakerx.com
You have to have the OSX installer on your disk: if you already installed it and it is gone, download it again from the Purchased tab of AppStore.

Comment: That's the thing, nothing at all went wrong, the El Capitan bootable drive is there, i'm just confused as to why the windows one is too.

Answer (score 0):

Startup Manager detects any bootable media. Since you've designated the drive as bootable, it presumes there's something bootable installed there. You've likely created a bootable Windows drive, so that's what Startup Manager says, even if there's no actual Windows present.

Comment: I didn't create a bootable windows drive, I wiped a USB and used this guide to create a bootable El Capitan drive http://osxdaily.com/2015/09/30/create-os-x-el-capitan-boot-install-drive/

Comment: Did you format it GUID or MBR? The guide doesn't seem to mention that.

Comment: Mac Os extended (Journaled), just so confused as to why it's giving me a non-existent windows boot drive. Windows users get the "J" too booting from USB http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f217/windows-7-not-booting-up-letter-j-643978.html

Comment: Mac OS extended (HFS+) is what goes on top of the format type, MBR or GUID. As pretty much every USB will be supplied as MBR, this is still my prime suspect.